# Finding Polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

[Problem 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i09ZS.png)

So far I have

P0(a0)=1 P0(a1)=0 P0(a2)=0 P0(a3)=0 | P1(a0)=0 P1(a1)=1 P1(a2)=0 P1(a3)=0 |P2(a0)=0 P2(a1)=0 P2(a2)=1 P2(a3)=0 | P3(a0)=0 P3(a1)=0 P3(a2)=0 P3(a3)=1 which follows the rule stated in the hint. Would my next step be to use the Lagrange Polynomial formula to find each individual polynomial?

Comment: Looks like the problem just asks you to construct the [Lagrange basis polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial)

Answer (score 1):

If  $a\not  \in \{b,c,d\}$ and $p(x)=[\;(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)\;]\; /\;[\;(a-b)(a-c)(a-d)\;]$ then p(a)=1 and p(b)=p(c)=p(d)=0.